# Thumbnail limit max ''6''

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-modules, field

I'm using Drupal 7 and create a module for my content thumbnail images frontpage display. Working this:

```
 if(count($p_detail->field_slide) > 0){
            $output .= '<div class="right">';
            $output .= '<ul class="thumbs">';
            $i=6;
            foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb):
                $img_path = $thumb['uri'];
                $img_url = image_style_url('tmb_240x117', $img_path);
                $img_file = '<img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$p_detail->title.'" />';


                $output .= '<li>
                                <a href="'.$p_url.'">
                                    '.$img_file.'
                                    <div class="shadow"></div>    
                                    <div class="hoverimg"></div>
                                 </a>
                                <div class="img_no">0'.$i.'</div>
                            </li>';
                $i--;
            endforeach;
            $output .= '</ul>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
```

My thumbnails, field_slide and i want only first 6 thumbnails (if have 6 images... for exam, have 2 images, display 2 thumbnails)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try not to use HTML in your PHP code. I strongly suggest to use some templating for that. But anyway, to answer your question:

You can do two things:

**Answer 1 (preferred):**

Limit the number of items retrieved from your data source (usually a database) that are stored in:

```
$p_detail->field_slide
```

**Answer 2 (the easy, not so nice way):**

Create a counter ($i) and use a if-statement in your foreach. Something like:

```
$i = 6;
foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb) {
    if($i > 0) {
        // Your current code here
        $i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right? 

$i = 6;
foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb) {
    if($i > 0) {
if(count($p_detail->field_slide) > 0){
                $output .= '<div class="right">';
                $output .= '<ul class="thumbs">';
                $i=1;
                foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb):
                    $img_path = $thumb['uri'];
                    $img_url = image_style_url('tmb_240x117', $img_path);
                    $img_file = '<img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$p_detail->title.'" />';

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick. I can't really read it that well though, so I might miss something. As you are choosing the easy way, you might run in trouble later. For example, if you have 10.000.000 records in your database, you now ask for all 10.000.000 records and limit them at the last moment. You should try limiting those retrieved records BEFORE you store them in $p_detail->field_slide...

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to your method with returns your resources, the parameter tells your method the amount of resources you want to receive and then use this parameter in your sql query to do a limit.